# Jest and ES2015 imports. Make jest respect the pkg.module declaration in package.json

Tags: npm, module, ecmascript-6, node-modules, jestjs

I am importing [deepmerge](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/deepmerge) via npm in my app. The environment includes webpack, babel, typescript, react, redux, jest.

I managed to make Jest work fine with ES2015 imports, but Jest is refusing to use the es.js version of deepmerge (see [pkg.module](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/pkg.module) for reference).

Briefly, deepmerge is using a package named [rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup), which compiles both an ES2015 distribution and a different distribution for CommonJS-compatible environments and libraries like RequireJS. They are then referenced in deepmerge's package.json like this:

```
  "main": "dist/umd.js",
  "module": "dist/es.js"
```

This way, when importing deepmerge in the app the compiler should be wise enough to use the correct file according to the environment in which it is running.

This is probably oversimplified, but you should get the point.

Now, my app is parsing everything just fine and the right version of the script is being compiled (`es.js`). Jest, instead, imports the wrong file (`umd.js`) thus breaking the tests (`TypeError: deepmerge_1.default is not a function`).

I have found workarounds, like specifying the path to the correct file in the import statement rather than relying on `import deepmerge from 'deepmerge';`. But I feel there should be a better way that is more future-proof in case the maintainer of the package decides to change the path, the filename or whatever.

Any idea?

---

jest.config.json

```
{
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!deepmerge)"
  ],
  "transform": {
    ".(js|ts|tsx)": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
  },
  "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json"]
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"],
  "plugins": [
    "react-css-modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: did you ever find a fix for this? I am running into exact same issue

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Tweaked a bit so it uses the package's module field. Because of jest.mock's [hoisting](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2567), wasn't able to make a helper function and had to repeat the name three times.

```
jest.mock('modulename', () => require('modulename/' + require('modulename/package.json').module));
```

---

Original Answer:

I've ran into the same problem when importing one of our own internal libraries that uses package.module. My understanding is that because JEST is run in node (and our tests do not go through WebPack), package.module is ignored and package.main is used instead.

I was able to workaround this using mocks from within the test:

```
jest.mock('modulename', () => require('modulename/builds/es'));
```

This is tedious to do for each module that uses pkg.module, but beats manually mocking out its contents and I can leave the tested code's imports intact.

Another approach could be to write a transform that would map/proxy the es version of the module to the commonjs version, but it didn't get me too far.

I am hoping for a better solution in the future.